# Cantor-Bendixon rank of a closed set in an arbitrary topological space

Tags: general-topology

If $(X,\tau)$ is a topological space, and $Y\subseteq X$ is a closed subset we can define the [Cantor-Bendixon derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_set_%28mathematics%29) of $Y$: $Y^0 = Y$, $Y^1 = Y^\prime, \ldots , Y^\alpha, \ldots$.

When $X=\mathbb{R}$, I found a [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270856/cantor-bendixson-theorem-proof) that the transfinite sequence of Cantor-Bendixon derivatives stabilizes, but does it stabilize for an arbitrary topological space $X$? If this is true, could anyone provide a link for the proof?

Comment: Do you know the basics of ordinals?

Comment: I think I do, however  I could be wrong.....

Comment: The sequence of sets $Y^\alpha$ is decreasing. Now use Hartogs's result that for any set $T$ there is an ordinal $\alpha$ that does not inject into $T$ (note that this is even provable without using the axiom of choice).

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I see that it is decreasing, but why is it stabilizing at some ordinal $\lambda$? I am fine using choice, but I still don't see it. I guess I don't know the basics about ordinals :)

Comment: I am also confused, as the proof  for the reals linked in the question, seems to be more involved. Obviously I am missing something.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(X, \tau)$ be an arbitrary topological space. We recursively define the sequence of its Cantor-Bendixson derivates $(X_\alpha)_{\alpha \in ON}$ as follows

- $X_0 := X$
- $X_{\alpha +1 } := X_{\alpha}'$ (the set of limit points of $X_{\alpha}$)
- $X_\lambda := \bigcap_{\alpha < \lambda} X_\alpha$

This defines a decreasing sequence
$$
X_0 \supseteq X_1 \supseteq \ldots
$$

Assume towards a contradiction that this sequence doesn't stabilize. Then

$$
f \colon ON \rightarrow \mathcal P (X), \alpha \mapsto X_\alpha
$$

is an injection $ON \rightarrow \mathcal P(X)$, which is impossible as $ON$ is a proper class.

Comment: Oh, I see now, thank you. Just to make sure, in the answer to the linked question for the real, the crux is not that it stabilizes, but that it stabilizes at a countable ordinal, right?

Comment: @Markus Yes, you're right. Note that this holds for every separable space.